# Trouble converting delete sql to JPA

Tags: java, oracle, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I have an app that is currently using the following derived query to find messages in a db and then using the repository.delete() function to delete them:

`Page<Message> findAllByMessageTypeEqualsAndCreateTimestampBefore(@Param("type") String type, @Param("date")Date date, @Param("page") Pageable pageable);`

We use the pagination here to only select the first 500 rows, as the db we're working with it housing a lot of data and we need this sql to be efficient. The problem with this current design is that the *Message* table has some really large fields with raw message data in them and it's slowing the delete down. If I were to use an sql to do the same delete in the db, I'd use:

```
delete from message where transactionid in (
select transactionid from message where message_type in (type)
                                    and create_timestamp < sysdate - <age tolerance for this message type>
                            and  rownum < 500 )
```

I'm trying to find an elegant way to convert this sql to JPA, so I can effectively do the same delete but without querying up the entire record every time I delete. When I tried converting the sql to a nativequery, I got a "fetch out of sequence" exception from Oracle. This is what I tried:

```
    @Query(nativeQuery = true, value = "delete from message where transactionid in (\n" +
            "select transactionid from message where message_type in ?1 \n" +
            "                                    and create_timestamp < ?2 \n" +
            "                            and  rownum < 500 )")
    Integer deleteByMessageTypeAndCreateTimestampBefore(@Param(value = "messageType") String messageType, @Param("maxAge") Date maxAge);
```

Is there a way I can do this better? Basically I need to delete by message type and create timestamp of the record, but without having to query up the whole record first. Thanks!

Comment: Can you share your entity definition ?

Answer (score 0):

You can move your conditions in the select to the delete statement:

```
delete from message where message_type in ?1 and create_timestamp < ?2
```

If you are using Spring JPA repositories, the above query can be defined as the following method in your repository:

```
Long deleteByMessageTypeInAndCreateTimestampLessThan(List<MessageType> types, Date maxAge);
```